# Multiple aggregation user defined functions in Dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, aggregation, dask

I'm processing a data set using Dask (considering it doesn't fit in memory) and I want to group the instances with a different aggregating function depending on the column and it's type.

Dask has a set of default aggregation functions for numerical data types, but not for strings/objects. Is there a way to implement a user defined aggregation function for strings somewhat similar to the example below?

```
atts_to_group = {'A', 'B'}
agg_fn = {
  'C': 'mean'  #int
  'D': 'concatenate_fn1'  #string - No default fn for strings - Doesn't work
  'E': 'concatenate_fn2'  #string
}
ddf = ddf.groupby(atts_to_group).agg(agg_fn).compute().reset_index()
```

At this point I'm able to read the whole data set in memory upon dropping irrelevant columns/rows, but I'd prefer continuing the processing in Dask considering it's faster performing the required operations.

Edit:
Tried adding a custom function directly onto the dictionary:

```
def custom_concat(df):
    ...
    return df_concatd

agg_fn = {
  'C': 'mean'  #int
  'D': custom_concat(df)
}

-------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: unknown aggregate Dask DataFrame Structure:
```

Comment: If dask is anything like pandas, you can reference a user defined function. Simply do not call it by a string literal and of course it should exist, defined with a `def` or `lambda` receiving a series parameter and returning a series. Please show function assignment. And *doesn't work* is not helpful. Post errors/undesired results.

Comment: @Parfait I just realised there's a costume aggregation function. I implemented the solution in 2 different ways on the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realised Dask provides with an [Aggregation data structure](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate). The custom aggregation can be done as follows:

```
# Concatenates the strings and separates them using ","
custom_concat = dd.Aggregation('custom_sum', lambda x: ",".join(str(x)), lambda x0: ",".join(str(x0)))
custom_concat_E = ...

atts_to_group = {'A', 'B'}
agg_fn = {
  'C': 'mean'  #int
  'D': custom_concat_D
  'E': custom_concat_E
}
ddf = ddf.groupby(atts_to_group).agg(agg_fn).compute().reset_index()
```

This can also be done with *Dataframe.apply* for a less verbose solution

```
def agg_fn(x):
    return pd.Series(
        dict(
            C = x['C'].mean(), # int
            D = "{%s}" % ', '.join(x['D']), # string (concat strings)
            E = ...
        )
    )

ddf = ddf.groupby(atts_to_group).apply(agg_fn).compute().reset_index
```

Comment: Dear @giesOr, how would you provide a meta attribute for the dask.apply function in this situation of a returned dictionary?